# calculating Average of each cell across multiple csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

i have multiple csv files (n) with fixed headers and 100 rows, and i'm trying to calculate the average (or other things such as Min or Max) of all [i][j] elements of these tables and store it in one final csv table. I tried genfromtxt but it did not workout. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt


a=genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\my_pc\\Desktop\\a1.csv',delimiter=';' , skip_header=1, dtype=None, encoding='utf_8')
b=genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\my_pc\\Desktop\\a2.csv',delimiter=';' , skip_header=1, dtype=None, encoding='utf_8')
c=genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\my_pc\\Desktop\\a3.csv', delimiter=';' , skip_header=1, dtype=None, encoding='utf_8')

#average
d = (a + b+ c) /3
print(d)
```

which i get this error :

[image]

How can i do this ? and also please tell me, whether `genfromtxt` parameter is right or not?)

Comment: If you showed the content of your csv files as text (what they are) instead of through a spreadsheet image, we could try to reproduce... Remember, a csv file is a **text** file!

Comment: @Serge Ballesta this spreadsheet something that i randomly generated in excel and saved it as csv. But it represent the exact format of my data

Comment: That is not the question. I can copy paste from a csv presented as text, but not from an image. It is much easier to help when the question contains a [mcve]...

Comment: @Justice_Lords makes no difference as long as it wokrs better. but please remember that the final result should be in a data frame, so i can use it for further calculations. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("a1.csv")
for i in range(2,21):
       filename="a"+str(i)+".csv"
       df+=pd.read_csv(filename)
df=df/20
```

This should do the trick..

Comment: One more question, how should i put this in a for loop, because i have 20 data sets , could you help me with that as well?

Comment: @SaeidHedayati Can you try now?

Comment: sorry for the late respond. I tried it  but i just keep getting this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` .

Comment: @SaeidHedayati You have to post full code so that I can help you. But I think it would be better if you post another question with sample datasets. Maybe try to load the data individually and check for its **type**. I think this problem has something to do type conversion. Try to convert "str" to "float" before adding.